# Why is the text selection tool is half shown and is not clickable

Tags: android, android-appcompat, textselection, appcompatdialog

I have an `AppCompatActivity` which contains `android.app.Fragment`. In fragment I have a button on the toolbar which fires the method `showDialog()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add_ingredient) {
        showDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showDialog() {
    // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog
    // characteristics
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_ingredient_add_title);
    builder.setView(mActivityMain.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_shopping_ingredient_add, null));
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ingredient_ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_ingredient_cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
    dialog = builder.create();

    dialog.show();
}
```

As it can be seen from the code, a `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` appears.
[Picture 1. AlertDialog shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIG5k.png)
Then I select some text.
[Picture 2. Text selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJrgt.png)
And somehow text selection tool shows only half of it and is unclickable.
[image: Picture 3. Problem]

My `styles.xml` file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- colorPrimary is used, for instance, for the default ActionBar (but not Toolbar) background. We specify the same color for the toolbar background in toolbar.xml.. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar (with the battery, clock, etc). -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated which is used to tint widgets. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuTextApearance</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color_highlight_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color_highlight_text</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/color_highlight_text</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/myapp_action_mode_background</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#00000000</item>
</style>

<style name="HeaderBar">
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="HeaderBarTransparent">
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary_transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Question:

- How can I make the text selection tool fully visible and clickable?